# How to fix pending issue regarding mongoose with axios post

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, axios

I'm working on a person project that requires data from a redux form to be sent to an express server through an axios call. I've got the data from the client to the server by using body-parser but am having problems saving to the MongoDB using mongoose. Why am I getting a pending request on my post call?

```
<code>
    // Client side axios post call
    export const createSchedule = formValues => async (dispatch, getState) => {
        const res = await axios.post("/schedule/create", {
            data: {
                userId: getState().auth.googleId,
                title: formValues.title,
                description: formValues.description
            }
        });
        dispatch({ type: CREATE_SCHEDULE, payload: res });
    };

</code>
<code>
    // server side axios post call 
    module.exports = app => {
        app.post("/schedule/create", async (req, res) => {
            const schedule = new Schedule({
                googleId: req.body.data.userId,
                title: req.body.data.title,
                description: req.body.data.description
            }).save(function(err) {
                if (err) console.log("saved failed.");
                else console.log("saved");
            });
            done(null, schedule);
        });
    };
</code>

<code>

    // Schedule schema for mongoose
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const { Schema } = mongoose;

    const scheduleSchema = new Schema(
        {
            googleId: String,
            title: String,
            description: String,
            date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
        },
        { collection: "schedules" }
    );

    mongoose.model("schedules", scheduleSchema);

</code>
```

Pending results in client console

TypeError: Schedule is not a constructor error in server console.

Comment: Could you show some more context? For example, how is `Schedule` defined? Error `Schedule is not a constructor` is kinda self explanatory - you need to export mongoose model and then import it properly.

Answer (score 0):

It worked out by changing how I accessed the Schedule model in my api call. I previously had imported it locally instead of using the mongoose.model("schedules") line that I should've used.